# script is not supposed to run when including a file

Tags: php

I am creating a quote which requires input that is taken in another page.
It is returned in an array on the get-cms-form-results.php page and I'd like to use the returned values in my index.php.

I pass a secret in my url to the get-cms-form-results.php for it to work, and when I don't it tells me no secret specified.

The problem for me is currently that whenever I include the get-cms-form-results.php in my index.php:

```
include 'get-cms-form-results.php';
```

It does show the error no secret specified when running my index, instead of just allowing me access to the array in that page.

I would like it not to run the script but just allow me access to stuff such as variables from this file.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the code on both files?

Comment: I can't really, it's a huge piece of code. I don't think it is necessary anyways.